# Почему кнопка с клавиатуры в Unity при запуске игры обрабатывается только с третьего нажатия?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TabletOpening : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isTabletOpened = false;
    public GameObject Tablet_Menu;

    void Awake()
    {
        Tablet_Menu = GameObject.Find("TabletMenu");
        Tablet_Menu.SetActive(false);
    }


    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            if (!isTabletOpened)
            {
                Tablet_Menu.SetActive(true);
                isTabletOpened = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Tablet_Menu.SetActive(false);
                isTabletOpened = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске игры при нажатии кнопки Tab, чтобы открыть планшет первый раз, она срабатывает только с третьего раза. Далее все работает корректно. В чем причина и как исправить?

Comment: Код выглядит нормально. Для начала поменяйте доступ к полям с `public` на `private`.